# Is the LS estimator of the coefficient unbiased when X'X is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I learned that when regressing on a simple linear model $y=X{\beta}+{\varepsilon}$,
the LS estimator for $\beta$ is given as
${\hat{\beta}}=(X'X)^{-}X'y$, and that ${\hat{\beta}}=(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ when $X'X$ is nonsingular.

I can see that $X{\hat{\beta}}$ is unbiased regardless of the singularity of $X'X$, but what I am not sure of is whether $\hat{\beta}$ itself is unbiased when $X'X$ is singular. The expectation would be given as
$E(\hat{\beta})=E((X'X)^{-}X'X\beta+(X'X)^{-}X'\varepsilon)=(X'X)^{-}X'X\beta$

So am I right in thinking that there is no guarantee that $\hat{\beta}$ is unbiased when $X'X$ is singular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design matrix $X$ is typically a tall skinny matrix (i.e. having more rows than columns). If the columns of $X$ are linearly independent then $X'X$ is nonsingular. Otherwise $X'X$ is singular and then the least-squares estimator of $\beta$ is not unique.

The fitted values of $y,$ on the other hand, are still unique and unbiased. The fitted vector $\widehat{y\,}$ is just the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the column space of $X.$ The non-uniqueness of $\widehat\beta$ just means there's more than one way to write $\widehat{y\,}$ as linear combination of the columns of $X.$ The existence of more than one such way is how we know that the LS estimator is not unique.